# Delete s3 object from bucket using rails

Tags: amazon-s3

I have tried this `s3.buckets[BUCKET].objects[mykey].delete` to delete my s3 object. But it did not work. When i googled they have given this. What is the correct one ?

Answer (score 0):

That was ruby v1 - I assume (and suggests) you use ruby sdk v2, the following code will work (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#delete_object-instance_method)

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: region_name,
  credentials: credentials,
  # ...
)

resp = client.delete_object({
  bucket: "BucketName", # required
  key: "ObjectKey", # required
  version_id: "ObjectVersionId" # if you enabled s3 versioning
})
```